# Spring Data JPA and startsWith repository

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Spring Data JPA repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "product")
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Integer> {

    @RestResource(path = "nameStartsWith", rel = "nameStartsWith")
    Page findByNameStartsWithOrderByNameDesc(@Param("name") String name, Pageable p);


}
```

The definition of the Product class is obvious and is a mapped JPA entity on a postgresql database.

It works pretty nice, but it has an annoying problem which I couldn't fix.

I suppose that spring translate this method definition in a sql query with the like operator that uses `_` and `%` as wild cards. I'm afraid anyway that those character are not escaped when passed to this method, with the results that if I search for a product with a name that contains a `_` it gets understood as "any character", and this is bad due to the naming convention my products use.

I need a way to escape the name parameter before it gets passed to the method, but the only way I could think of is implementing the method myself loosing all the magic of spring data. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thank you!

PS I'm using spring boot 1.4.0

Comment: Have you encountered a problem?

Comment: I would first check that Spring doesn't already escape the % and _ characters and produce the right SQL query, instead of just assuming. You might be right, but maybe it already takes care of that. Turn SQL logging on and see what is produced.

Comment: Hi JB, the behavior of the method is obvious as it returns products with any character in place of _, so or it is not escaped or there is bigger bug somewhere inside spring data. Anyway just looking at hibernate logs confirm what I said: the query generated uses the like operator and the parameter is the one  given in input not escaped.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap around a custom sql query around this method by using `@Query` annotation. Here is the relevant documentation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query